# ISO file extraction

Tags: iso

How do I extract an `.iso` file so that I am able to use the contents of it. Please be sure that it's not a operating system file, its just a file which contains videos.

I have tried to extract it using the default archive extractor it gave me an error:

> An error occurred while extracting files.ignoring out-of-order file@13((null)) 38912<472668160

I have also tried to mount it and it created a drive inside the Network option of file explorer but no videos run successfully, it just shows a video player screen. Please tell me how can I come out of this issue.

Comment: This could be a corrupted `iso` file. Can you copy/download it again?

Comment: @AlaaAli No not corrupted. I have the same issue even i can extracted successfully on windows. Issue is only on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If mounting inside your file explorer, try mounting it this way:

```
mkdir /mnt/iso_folder
mount -o loop image.iso /mnt/iso_folder
```

Then you should be able to access the files that are located on the disk.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "ISO Master" to Read, write and modify ISO images. Link below

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/isomaster/